# Spyder Duplicates on TaskBar

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

Can anybody advise why I get this duplicate icon for Spyder on task bar and when I right click it, I see python and not spyder?  Please do not indicate for me to set the AppUserModelID to spyderlib.Spyder using Win7AppId.  This does NOT work for me.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Did you create a Matplotlib plot before this happened? Or does it happen all the time?

Comment: Happens all the time.  Something happened after I update anaconda where windows wouldn't even allow to me open .py files with Spyder even on opens with.  I had to update the registry OpensWithList to open the path C:\Users\bjwil\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe C:\Users\***\Anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py which is the target for Anaconda shortcut.  I also had to add a new binary file Python.File to the OpenWithProgids to open with Spyder.  They open with Spyder only through the python.exe not even pythonw.exe.  I was using Matplotlib as well and having issue install mayavi.  Windows issue?  Added pics

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what happens then.